# Sender Type options not available

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, org-wide-defaults

According to the documentation the **Send Email** core action (for a screen flow) should have the options of CurrentUser, DefaultWorkflowUser or OrgWideEmailAddress in the SenderType.

However none of these options are showing up for me. Or I am simply unable to find them. Sender Type dropdown shows a lot of options but not the releavant ones.

Am I missing something here? Or is there some setting I need to turn on for this to work?

Comment: Have you seen the `Sender Type` input parameter in the email action?

Comment: **[Sender Type](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5)**  see in this documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me to literally copy-paste the values "CurrentUser", "DefaultWorkflowUser" or "OrgWideEmailAddress" in the Sender Type. Instead of trying to find it in the dropdown options. Very counter intuitive.